# Trouble Calling a Function Within the For Loop of Another Function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, for-loop

Im having some trouble writing a program and was wondering if somebody could help. Here is my code so far:

```
def parseExtension(filename):

    periodPosition = filename.find(".")
    extension = (filename[periodPosition + 1:])
    return extension


def fileExtensionExists(fileList, fileExtension):
    for fileName in fileList:
        return(parseExtension(fileList))
    return

print(fileExtensionExists( ["python.exe", "assignment5.docx", 
"assignment4.py", "shortcuts.docx", "geographyhw1.txt"], "py"))
```

The program consists of two functions. The first function you see takes each file from the file list, finds the period, and returns what comes after it, aka the extension.

The second function (main function) is where im having trouble. The second function is suppose to call the first function in a for loop to receive the extensions of all the files in the list, and then compare all the returned extensions to the second hard coded parameter, "py" or "fileExtension" within the function. If there are "py" files in the list, the function should return true, if not, it should return false.

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: Start by comparing each returned extension to the second hard coded parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to supply `fileName` in the `parseExtension` function call. But then you have some more issues. I think what you want is this.

```
def parseExtension(filename):
    periodPosition = filename.find(".")
    extension = (filename[periodPosition + 1:])
    return extension


def fileExtensionExists(fileList, fileExtension):
    for fileName in fileList:
        if parseExtension(fileName) == fileExtension:
            return True
    return False

my_files = ["python.exe", "assignment5.docx", "assignment4.py", 
            "shortcuts.docx", "geographyhw1.txt"]

print(fileExtensionExists(my_files, "py"))
```

Comment: Edit: It keeps returning false because it only runs the parseExtension on the first element in the list. If I change the file to a .py, it will return true. How would I make the for loop run through all elements of the list before returning true or false? Or at least run through till it receives a true?

Comment: This should not happen. If the first argument you give to `fileExtensionExists` is a list, it will call `parseExtension` for every element of that list. The output of `parseExtension` will be compared to `fileExtension` and if it is the same, the function `fileExtensionExists` will immediately return with `True`. If it has not returned after the last element, the function will return `False`. By the way: The things that Duncan pointed out in his answer about splitting are correct. Try to improve your code in that way as well

Answer (score 1):

`return` exits the function, it won't continue executing the function after a `return` statement.

Either build up your results in a list and then return them after the end of the `for` loop, or use `yield` to pass them back one at a time (but then you need to use a loop or construct a `list` from the results).

```
def fileExtensionExists(fileList, fileExtension):
    extensions = []
    for fileName in fileList:
        extensions.append(parseExtension(fileList))
    return extensions
```

or

```
def fileExtensionExists(fileList, fileExtension):
    for fileName in fileList:
        yield parseExtension(fileList)

print(list(fileExtensionExists( ["python.exe", "assignment5.docx", 
    "assignment4.py", "shortcuts.docx", "geographyhw1.txt"], "py")))
```

BTW, unless this is a school exercise, do yourself a favour and use use `os.path.splitext()` to split off the extension, there's really no need to re-invent the wheel here, Python comes with lots of wheels. `splitext()` will include the period in front of the extension so you would want to pass in `".py"` but that usually keeps code cleaner in any case.

Comment: should have specified in the question that my code wasnt complete, I was just stuck and didnt know where to go with the second function. And yes this is for school work.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop does nothing: it returns after the first element off the list `fileExtensionExists` exits at the first `return` met